# Proper HTTP status to return for hacking attempts

Tags: http-status-codes

I have a system that logs information and sometimes find a particular IP address doing something nasty, like trying to exploit phpMyAdmin (even though it isn't even installed on the system).

When I find these offenders, I add the IP address to a block list that returns a small message whether the page exists or not and log the IP address and their query string so I can keep tabs on them.

Problem is, most of them appear to be scripts that scan, and I am still technically returning a HTTP status code of 200 with the small message. I want to be more forward with the status code, but I am not sure which one best applies.

I found the list [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), and it seems that `401` or `403` best apply. Which is the best code for "banning" an IP address?

Comment: It's often best to just drop the connection entirely, preferably at the firewall, rather than giving an HTTP response at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`403` or `404` is best suited. See the reference for `403`:

*"(...) If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead."*

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.4

For example you can return a status `403 - Forbidden` and describe the reason in the response body. I'm not sure whether it is allowed to return a status code like `403 - Banned for ...`. In any case, innocent users are probably especially interested in the reason for the 403.